# All Li's in one list should have the same height as the highest item

Tags: css

i have a list with three items (li's). I want that the two remaining li's of that list have the same height as the highest item in that list. How can i do that with CSS?

Example: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/EJFpd

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use `display: table-cell` to get table like layouts](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/csvfb):

```
.box-page-ul {
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box-page-ul li {
  background-color: #60615c;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 294px; 
  display: table-cell;
}
```

You have the limitations that you can't use margins to separate the `li` elements anymore, and also that they won't flow on to multiple lines like they would with `float`.  If you need those then you'll have to resort to JavaScript, or wait until [CSS Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) matures.

Comment: If the margins around the elements are uniform, the `border-spacing` property can be used on the associated table element.

Comment: @cimmanon In his original code they weren't uniform, but could probably manage by using both `border-spacing` and `border-width`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
display: table-cell;
```

Here fiddle with your corrected code http://jsfiddle.net/rwxdp/